# Há como juntar vários SELECTS em apenas uma query?

Tags: php, sql, select, sql-select

Possuo uma página onde terei que fazer várias consultas ao banco. No momento, são um total de três tabelas. São elas: `cadastro`, `publicacoes` e `estilo`. Atualmente faço da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT nome, sobrenome, usuario, email FROM cadastro WHERE usuario = "$usuario" LIMIT 1;

SELECT conteudo, data, hora, usuario FROM publicacoes WHERE usuario = "$usuario" ORDER BY id LIMIT 5;

SELECT cor1, cor2, cor3, usuario FROM estilo WHERE usuario = "$usuario" LIMIT 1;
```

Todas as consultas são feitas e então eu manipulo cada `query` através do `foreach...`.

Minha dúvida é: Há alguma maneira de juntar todas essas querys em uma única consulta, assim deixando o código mais "clean" e performático?

Comment: Sim é possível, nesse caso precisa fazer join, pode começar [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/91)

Comment: Eu já havia visto essa questão ontem mesmo. Mas a dúvida é: pode-se usar join mesmo sem relacionar as tabelas (que é o meu caso)? Ou estou falando besteira?

Comment: Se entendi direito, a informação que elas tem em comum é o campo `usuario` ele será o criterio de junção.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT C.*, P.*, E.* FROM cadastro as C
LEFT JOIN publicacoes AS P ON C.usuario = P.usuario
LEFT JOIN estilo AS E ON C.usuario = E.usuario) RESULTADO WHERE usuario = '".$usuario."'  `

Answer (score 2):

Acho que essa query resolve o seu problema , vc pode juntar elas usando inner join pois tem a referencia do usuário ( Considerando que usuário seja único )

```
     SELECT cadastro.nome, cadastro.sobrenome, cadastro.usuario, cadastro.email,publicacoes.conteudo, publicacoes.data, publicacoes.hora, estilo.cor1,estilo.cor2, estilo.cor3 
     FROM publicacoes INNER JOIN cadastro ON cadastro.usuario =publicacoes.usuario 
     INNER JOIN estilo ON estilo.usuario = publicacoes.usuario 
     WHERE usuario = "$usuario" limit 5
```